# xq mi pagina me da este error Uncaugth (in promise) SyntaxError: JSon.parse: unexpected character

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, css

Estoy haciendo una pagina web(sitio de ventas) con base de datos incluida(sql) estoy usando html, css, js y php.

En el punto en el que estoy es el de agregar al carrito un contador con la cantidad de productos que llevo y al hacer el codigo me da este error

**Uncaugth (in promise) SyntaxError: JSon.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the json data.**

Aca les dejo el codigo

**La funcion de js**

```
function addProducto(id, token){
 let url = 'clases/carrito.php'
 let formData = new FormData()
 formData.append('id', id)
 formData.append('token', token)


 fetch(ur,{
 method: 'POST',
 body: formData,
 mode: 'cors'
}) .then(response => response.json())
.then(data=> {
 if(data.ok){
  let elemento = document.getElementById(id del boton agregar al carrito)
elemento.innerHTML = data.numero
}
}) 
}
```

**Ahora la clase carrito.php**

```
<?php

require 'archivo config que esta bien echo, ese funciona, y lo unico para lo que se utiliza es para iniciar la session de php y mantener el contador en la pagina'

if(isset($_POST['id'])){
 $id = $_POST['id'];
$token = $_POST['token'];

$token_tmp = hash_hmac('sha1', $id, KEY_TOKEN);

if($token==$token_tmp){
If(isset($_SESSION['carrito']['producto'][$id])){
  $_SESSION['carrito']['producto'][$id]+=1;
} else{
  $_SESSION['carrito']['producto'][$id]=1;
}

$datos['numero'] = count( $_SESSION['carrito']['producto']);
$datos['ok']=true;
} else{
$datos['ok']=false;
}
} else{
$datos['ok']=false;
}

echo json_encode($datos);
```

Cual es el error para que me salga eso en la consola al inpeccionar em firefox o cualquier navegador y para que no me funcione el button de agregar al carrito(solo el contador)

Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Tenés la certeza de que `response` te devuelve algo válido? Por algo te dice _caracter inesperado_ ya al inicio :)

Comment: Ni idea , por eso pongo el codigo, el de carrito es el q me devuelve, y siempre fijo devuelve 1 o 0 o 0+1 o 1+1 o el numero q este en el contador + 1

Comment: ¿Tu variable se llama `url` o `ur`? Además, tenés que imprimir el valor de `response` para saber qué devuelve...

Comment: No, url es lq direccion donde esta el archivo que realiza el trabajo de contar, la vatiable que deveria devolver es ``` $datos['numero'] ```

Comment: Pues tienes el fetch a `ur` y no a `url`. Pero claro, como te gusta acortar palabras **pq** es "nice", tal vez no te diste cuenta. Revisa que el nombre de la variable pasado a `fetch` sea correcto.

Comment: Marco, en tu código estás haciendo `fetch` a una variable que se llama `ur`... Y eso no es nada chévere :)

Comment: Joder si, creo q ahi esta el error q debe ir url no ur. Gracias

Comment: Nono, no era eso, en la pc lo tengo bien

Comment: cambia esto:  `response.json()` por esto: `console.log(response);` y lo que salga en la consola del navegador lo pegas aqui completo.

Comment: Ya lo hice. La consola dice lo siguiente.

Comment: Uncaugth (in promise) TypeError: data is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data" indica que hay un problema en el formato JSON que se está devolviendo desde el servidor.

En tu archivo carrito.php, después de asignar los valores a $datos, estás utilizando json_encode($datos) para convertir el arreglo $datos en una cadena JSON y enviarla como respuesta al cliente. Sin embargo, es posible que haya algún otro contenido antes de la llamada a echo json_encode($datos), como un espacio en blanco, una línea en blanco o algún texto adicional, que está causando el error.

Para solucionar este problema, asegúrate de que no haya ningún contenido antes de echo json_encode($datos). Verifica si hay espacios en blanco o líneas en blanco antes o después de las etiquetas de apertura y cierre de PHP (), ya que eso podría generar el error. Asegúrate de que el archivo carrito.php solo contenga código PHP y no tenga ningún espacio o línea en blanco antes o después del código.

Aquí está el código corregido del archivo carrito.php sin espacios o líneas en blanco adicionales:

```
<?php
require 'archivo config que esta bien echo, ese funciona, y lo unico para lo que se utiliza es para iniciar la session de php y mantener el contador en la pagina'

if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
  $id = $_POST['id'];
  $token = $_POST['token'];

  $token_tmp = hash_hmac('sha1', $id, KEY_TOKEN);

  if ($token == $token_tmp) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['carrito']['producto'][$id])) {
      $_SESSION['carrito']['producto'][$id] += 1;
    } else {
      $_SESSION['carrito']['producto'][$id] = 1;
    }

    $datos['numero'] = count($_SESSION['carrito']['producto']);
    $datos['ok'] = true;
  } else {
    $datos['ok'] = false;
  }
} else {
  $datos['ok'] = false;
}

echo json_encode($datos);
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias ahora si me funciona. Un millon de gracias

Comment: Marco, te recomiendo usar ChatGPT directamente la próxima, ya que es lo que hizo AsterionArsenio con esta respuesta. Dió la casualidad que ChatGPT acertó en la solución de tu problema, pero si miras el perfil de Asterion verás que la mayoria de sus respuestas son con ChatGPT y no tienen nada que ver con la pregunta

Comment: busque muchisimo en chat gpt y no encontre

Comment: ahora ya me fuciona el carrito, pero solo en la parte de detalles, en la pagina inicial no, y al regresar de la de detalles se resetea, como puede arreglarlo.

Comment: **pense que usando esto en mi archivo config.php serviria**

Comment: ``` $num_cart = 0;
if(isset($_SESSION['carrito']['productos'])){
    $num_cart=count($_SESSION['carrito']['producto']);
} ```

Comment: donde num_cart es la variable que controla el contador en el carrito, como puedo haver para que funciones en la pagina **principal.php** y **en detalles.php** y que al cambiar de una a otra se mantenga el numero